# Find inconsistencies in two columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I am looking for help on finding inconsistencies between two columns from two different tables.

Table1 has ColumnA

Table2 has ColumnB

ColumnA and ColumnB have prefixes in front of them as well, for example.

```
ColumnA = TZ-ZA112
ColumnA = TZ-RT322
ColumnB = AX-ZA112
ColumnB = AX-RT311
```

So basically I need to remove the prefixes and then find the inconsistencies in the database. So the inconsistencies would be

```
ColumnA RT322
ColumnB RT311
```

So the values in the columns might exists in one and not exist in the other, so I have to find out where its existing and then remove them afterwards. I need help!

Not sure if this will help but this is what I used and it returned nothing.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 
    ON t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnB
WHERE t1.ColumnA != t2.ColumnB
```

Comment: Do you need general solution or just added multiple RDBMS tags?

Comment: Can you share some code for what you have tried so far, even if it's not working? It might be easier for others to suggest a solution if you can share something more specific.

Comment: @KevinHooke Added what I used, not sure if it is correct to begin with

Comment: @RyanVincent It's a project that I am helping someone with, I think he has until tomorrow, it does not have to be one huge query. I just need some guidance on how this could be done as I never came across a beast like this.

Comment: @RyanVincent Can you show an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach where you combine all the values from both tables and select only those that have a count of 1. `substring` works in SQL Server, if you are using a different database you might have to change the function accordingly.

```
select col from
(
select substring(columna,4,len(columna)) as col from tableA
union all
select substring(columnb,4,len(columnb)) from tableB
) t 
group by col 
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: I dont understand this, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The query you posted is almost exactly what you want. However, the where predicate is where you went wrong. When you have an outer join you have to check for NULL instead of inequality. Any value when compared to NULL is NULL and therefore will NOT be returned when checking for equality or inequality. Your where predicate as you posted is basically where TX-RT322 <> NULL.

A slight change to your where predicate and this should produce the results you want.

```
where t1.ColumnA is null
    or t2.ColumnB is null
```